# Joomla: Replace component relative links with site absolute (MVC)

Tags: php, joomla

I have reocurring problems with how links are handled in Joomla. On my dvelopment machine my component is accessed as `localhost/joomla/myview`. On the server it is `domain.com/myview2`. This raises a couple of problems, since I can't use absolute links. The main problems are:

Whenever I use a relative link like `?id=1` Joomla tries to turn it into `/?id=1`. For html links this can be fixed by omitting double quotes (`<a href='?id=1'>...<a>`). But that looks more like bug abuse than an actual fix.

Whenerver I use a link to another view of my component like `otherview?id=1` it doens't work on the server, since the views might have different names.

I expected `JRoute::_()` to fix this problem, but it seems to do nothing. Joomla does some link magic in the background, but it's doing it wrong and I don't know how to change that behavior.

Question: How do I make Joomla properly change component relative links to site absolute links for any possible view and site names?

Comment: You have to write code for managing the routes for ```sef``` url. Each component at site side there is a file called ```route.php``` at the component's root. You can check it out.

Comment: @kaetz please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.